# How to get back old Wi-Fi-button behavior in Control Center?

Tags: iphone, wifi, ios, control-center

In iOS 11 when we disable the Wi-Fi in the control center it doesn't actually disable the radio. According [to Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208086), the device is disconnected from Wi-Fi and auto-join is disabled until

- You turn on Wi-Fi in Control Center.
- You connect to a Wi-Fi network in Settings > Wi-Fi.
- **You walk or drive to a new location.**
- It's 5 AM local time.
- You restart your device.

When I disable Wi-Fi (or BT) I really want it off. Is it possible via some setting or application to get the old behavior back?

Comment: Workaround: turn on Airplane Mode and re-enable Cellular/Bluetooth.

Comment: @kenorb I think the question you [ultimately link to](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/300141/88313) came after this question (23-Sept vs 28-Sept).  So wouldn't that question be a duplicate of this question?

Comment: The canonical answer isn't necessarily the first, it's the one with the most interest & fullest answer, also hopefully an accepted one. (That it's my answer being debated has no relevance, purely coincidental... I can survive the rep hit if the canonical answer changes ;) Linking dupes [in any order] leads more people to a question that has a series of potential answers for their particular issue & lets google find more potential routes to that answer.

Comment: See: [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/191655).

Comment: I think it's actually duplicate of: [Wifi Automatically Turning ON after iOS 11 Update](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/300141/22781) which has definitely more votes and views.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple site you linked to indicates how to completely turn off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth:

> If you want to **completely disable** Wi-Fi and Bluetooth for all networks and devices, follow these steps:
>
> - To turn off Wi-Fi, go to `Settings > Wi-Fi` and turn off **Wi-Fi**.
> - To turn off Bluetooth, go to `Settings > Bluetooth` and turn off **Bluetooth**.
>
> For the best experience on your iOS device, try to keep Wi-Fi and Bluetooth turned on.

Comment: I am aware you can do it via settings > Wi-Fi. I asked about getting the old behavior back, i.e. toggle the button in the control center to switch the radio off.

Comment: No, as you've already found, Apple changed that behavior and there's no way, outside of jailbreaking, that will allow you to change that.