# Wifi Automatically Turning ON after iOS 11 Update

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm facing this issue after updating iOS11 in my recently bought iPhone 7

I usually turn off wifi during the night and found it ON in the morning. It automatically turns ON resulting in unnecessary battery drains.

Would appreciate a fix !!

Comment: I guess I got the issue. I'll verify & post the answer here. When I'm turning wifi OFF from control center by swiping upwards, it is just disconnecting but not turning wifi off. I guess in order to turn WIfi OFF, I've to go to Settings>>Wifi OFF. I need to verify this.

Comment: Just came across this question and I'm a little perplexed because I don't experience this problem, although my behaviour is a little different. In my case I use the Control Centre each night to switch on Aeroplane Mode.  This switches off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth and they **remain off** until I disable Aeroplane Mode in the morning. Sometimes this is well after 5am. So, is my experience different to yours in this regard? I'm running iOS 11.0.3, but I'm pretty sure it's been this way for each version of iOS 11.

Comment: [Shortcuts](https://itunes.apple.com/app/shortcuts/id915249334) introduced in iOS12 could be helpful. You may create a shortcut to turn WiFi / Bluetooth on / off.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WiFi & Bluetooth under iOS 11 will both automatically switch back on at 5am.

The only way to completely disable either is from Settings.

> If you want to completely disable Wi-Fi and Bluetooth for all networks and devices, follow these steps:
>
> - **To turn off *Wi-Fi*, go to *Settings > Wi-Fi* and turn off *Wi-Fi*.**
> - To turn off *Bluetooth*, go to *Settings > Bluetooth* and turn off *Bluetooth*.

Refs:

- [Apple KB - Use Bluetooth and Wi-Fi in Control Center with iOS 11](https://support.apple.com/HT208086)
- [Lifehacker - How to (Really) Turn Off Wi-Fi and Bluetooth in iOS 11](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-really-turn-off-wi-fi-and-bluetooth-in-ios-11-1818655697)